# Crystals Reports "Details" area printing on separate page from Report Header

Tags: crystal-reports, barcode

Here is my basic bar code template in Crystal Reports:

[image]

The problem is that when I try to print off this bar code everything in the Page Header and Details tabs print off on a separate page, in the end I get one page with the Report Header AND the Page Header, and another page also containing the page header and the details. When viewing the print preview, I can only see the headers and not the details. Why is this?

Comment: Increase the width of the details section and again check once..

Comment: @ankur Increasing nor decreasing the width of details or any other section has made a difference.

Comment: can show the print preview...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, originally ankur told me to Increase the width of the details section and check it again, so I did this to no avail. So instead I decreased the height of the entire thing as far as I could, as in the Page Setup the size of 1 page is 1.4 by 3 Inches, and could not be changed due to label printer limitations. Now that the page has been sized down to meet that 1.4x3 limitation, it prints on 1 page/label.